# Fill cells with a formula accroding respective rows

Tags: google-apps-script

Consider this picture from Google Sheet:

[image]

I want sum red cells be in the corresponding green cell.
But I have many rows, how I can do it such each corresponding green cell be sum of the self red row without writing formula for each green cells manually?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that colored cells are only for representation and not that you want a script to determine what to do with a cell by its color.

```
=byrow(A1:F8,lambda(z,sum(z)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this option
set in G1

```js
=IFERROR(COUNTBLANK(A1:F1);"")
```